# Regex: Separated tags accept Arabic or english

Tags: php, regex, yii, arabic

Hello I'm using Yii match validation and I need the tags input accept English and Arabic letters separated with commas:

should be accept in English or Arabic:

```
tag1, tag2, tag3, وسم4, tag4
```

or just Arabic:

```
وسم1، وسم2، وسم3
```

and please note that I need comma in English `,` and Arabic `،` working

and here is my regex I tried to use.. but it's not working:

```
/^[\w\s,]+$/ (working on english only )
/^[\w\s\p{Arabic}(,|،)]+$/ ( not working )
```

Comment: Try to add the `u` flag to handle utf8 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[\w\s]+(?:(?:,|،)[\w\s]+)*$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/5

```
$re = "/^[\\w\\s]+(?:(?:,|،)[\\w\\s]+)*$/mu"; 
$str = "tag1, tag2, tag3, وسم4, tag4\nوسم1، وسم2، وسم3"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: @Abudayah `u` is for unicode and `m` is for `multiline` .